# RailsアプリのActiverecordで、一括更新後テーブルのレコード(id)の順番が入れ替わってしまいます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, postgresql

以下のように新規登録を行いました。
その後、「編集」ボタンを押下して、商品名を「商品B」から「hogehoge」に変更しました。

「2 ステンレス 商品B F-078 10K 350A 3 P 2,000 3,000 4,000 9,000」
「2 ステンレス hogehoge F-078 10K 350A 3 P 2,000 3,000 4,000 9,000」
その後「登録」ボタンを押下したところ、レコードの順番が入れ替わって表示されました。
costsテーブルの中身も確認したところ、やはりレコードの順番が入れ替わって登録(更新)されていました。
考えられる原因はありますでしょうか？
思い当たる原因がありましたらアドバイス頂きたいです。
URLで申し訳ありません。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

https://github.com/hiro-hvk/sample_order_app

**新規登録時の入力内容**
符号  材質 / 部品NO   品名  型式  圧力  サイズ 数量  単位  仕入先A    仕入先B    仕入先C    売価                                          
1   ステンレス   商品A F-065   10K 300A    5   P   1,000   2,000   3,000   6,000
2   ステンレス   商品B F-078   10K 350A    3   P   2,000   3,000   4,000   9,000
3   ステンレス   商品C F-084   10K 400A    6   P   3,000   0   5,000   8,000

**更新時の入力内容**
符号  材質 / 部品NO   品名  型式  圧力  サイズ 数量  単位  仕入先A    仕入先B    仕入先C    売価                                          
1   ステンレス   商品A F-065   10K 300A    5   P   1,000   2,000   3,000   6,000
2   ステンレス   hogehoge    F-078   10K 350A    3   P   2,000   3,000   4,000   9,000
3   ステンレス   商品C F-084   10K 400A    6   P   3,000   0   5,000   8,000

**更新後の表示**
符号  材質 / 部品NO   品名  型式  圧力  サイズ 数量  単位  仕入先A    仕入先B    仕入先C    売価                                          
1   ステンレス   商品A F-065   10K 300A    5   P   1,000   2,000   3,000   6,000
3   ステンレス   商品C F-084   10K 400A    6   P   3,000   0   5,000   8,000
2   ステンレス   hogehoge    F-078   10K 350A    3   P   2,000   3,000   4,000   9,000

#### ※追記

costs_contoroller.rb

```
def index
  @costs = Cost.all.order(:id)
end
```

subjects_contoroller.rb

```
private

def set_subject
  @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  @subjects = @subject.costs.order(:id)
end
```

を追記しまして、views/subjects/ show.html.erb ではcostsテーブルの「id」順に並べることができました。

符号 材質 / 部品NO 品名 型式 圧力 サイズ 数量 単位 仕入先A 仕入先B 仕入先C 売価 
1 ステンレス 商品A F-065 10K 300A 5 P 1,000 2,000 3,000 6,000
2 ステンレス hogehoge F-078 10K 350A 3 P 2,000 3,000 4,000 9,000
3 ステンレス 商品C F-084 10K 400A 6 P 3,000 0 5,000 8,000

ただ、その後「編集」ボタンを押下したところ、views/subjects/edit.html.erbの_form.html.erbでは、レコードの順番が入れ替わったままでした。以下の状態でした。

符号 材質 / 部品NO 品名 型式 圧力 サイズ 数量 単位 仕入先A 仕入先B 仕入先C 売価 
1 ステンレス 商品A F-065 10K 300A 5 P 1,000 2,000 3,000 6,000
3 ステンレス 商品C F-084 10K 400A 6 P 3,000 0 5,000 8,000
2 ステンレス hogehoge F-078 10K 350A 3 P 2,000 3,000 4,000 9,000

このページもcostsテーブルの「id」順に並べることはできますでしょうか？
現状は、updateメソッド実行後にcostsテーブルのレコードの順番が入れ替わっている状況です。

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @subject.update(subject_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @subject, notice: 'Subject was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @subject }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @subject.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`costs#index` の処理だと思いますが、コントローラでは以下のように書かれています。

```
def index
  @costs = Cost.all
end
```

SQLデータベースでは明示しない限り順序は保証されません。(呼び出すごとに変化する可能性もあります。) 順序が問題になる場合は、必要に応じて `.order` を利用してソートしてください。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます！
`def index
@costs = Cost.all.order(:id)
end`
としました。
本文追記させて頂きました。
アドバイス頂けたら幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: コントローラーの`edit` で設定されてる `@costs` にも `order` を設定しましょう。おそらく `before_action`で呼び出されてる `set_costs` 内で代入されてるはずです。

Answer (score 1):

yasu さんが書かれたように、望んだ順序にするためには必ず `order` を付けましょう。

とくに、PostgreSQLをお使いのようですが、コイツは追記型でデータを書き込むので、更新すると「テーブル末尾に新たな内容でレコードを追加し、元のレコードを使わないようにする」という動作をします。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます！ ポスグレの仕様が原因だったのですね まさに指摘して頂いた現象と全く同じことが起こっています。この状況変えたいのですが、おすすめのデータベースはありますでしょうか？

Comment: もしくは何かしらの設定で回避することはできますでしょうか？